# JavaScript canvas tilemap rendering

Tags: javascript, sockets, canvas, socket.io, pug

I try to render tilemap using canvas but it appears only when I resize the window. When I refresh the page I see only a black screen but when resize window tilemap was rendered.

**Backend:**

```
socket.emit('server:tileMap', { tilemap, tileTypes });
```

**Frontend:**

```
socket.on('server:tileMap', ({ tilemap, tileTypes}) => {
    drawTilemap(tilemap, tileTypes)
});

let tilemapData = {};

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    resizeCanvas();
    drawTilemap(tilemapData.tilemap, tilemapData.tileTypes);
   drawBuildingTilemap(tilemapData.buildingData);
});

const drawTilemap = (tilemap, tileTypes) => {
    tilemapData['tilemap'] = tilemap;
    tilemapData['tileTypes'] = tileTypes;
    resizeCanvas();
    let x = 0, y = 0;

    for (const row of tilemap) {
        for (const el of row) {
           for (const type of tileTypes) {
               if (type[0] === el) {
                  const mapCanvas = $('#map-ctx');
                  const ctx = mapCanvas.getContext('2d', { alpha: false });
                  const img = new Image();

                  img.src = `/sprites/${type[1]}.png`;
                  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 32, 32);
               }
           }
           x += 32;
        }
        x = 0;
        y += 32;
   }
}
const resizeCanvas = () => {
    const map = $('.my-city');
    allCanvases.forEach(canvas => {
       canvas.height = map.offsetHeight;
       canvas.width = map.offsetWidth;
    })
```

Pug file

```
canvas#map-ctx
canvas#building-ctx
canvas#marked-ctx
include ../components/chunkInfo.pug
```

Comment: I don't see it in your code but it could be the background is rendered on top of the tilemap.

Comment: What I must change?

Comment: Is it an html page? If so pls add the html code.

Comment: I use pug

    canvas#map-ctx
    canvas#building-ctx
    canvas#marked-ctx